# Regex to not match group of characters

Tags: regex-negation

I want a regex to match a number string of length 5, but should not match group of 2 in middle of string
Eg. if my sample string is 12345 then i want 23 and 24 should not match in the string but should match 21, 22, 25

Should match
12145
12245
12567

Should not match
12345
12456

Can any please help me..

Comment: Do you mean a group of two digits *anywhere* in the string, or in a specific position?

Comment: Thank you for the accept. I improved the solution, for fun and in case you would have a more complex need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import re

pat = '\d(?!23|24)\d{4}'

rgx = re.compile(pat)

for x in ('12145','12245','12345','12456','12567'):
    print rgx.match(x)
```

result

```
12145 <_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x00AB01E0>
12245 <_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x00AB01E0>
12345 None
12456 None
12567 <_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x00AB01E0>
```

#### EDIT 1

If you need something a little more complex, that is to say excluding sucessions of 2 digits and successions of 3 digits starting at position 1:

```
import re

tu2 = (23,0,24,78,2,85,84,32)
tu3 = (333,899)

pat = '\d(?!%s|%s)\d{4}' % ('|'.join(map('{:02}'.format,tu2)),
                            '|'.join(map('{:03}'.format,tu3)))
print pat,'\n'

rgx = re.compile(pat)

for x in ('12145','12245','12345','12456','12567',
          '278455','13358','13337','18907','18995'):
    print x,rgx.match(x)
```

result

```
\d(?!23|00|24|78|02|85|84|32|333|899)\d{4} 

12145 <_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x011DB528>
12245 <_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x011DB528>
12345 None
12456 None
12567 <_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x011DB528>
278455 None
13358 <_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x011DB528>
13337 None
18907 <_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x011DB528>
18995 None
```

.

#### EDIT 2

Showing what can be done:

```
import re
from collections import defaultdict

conditions = ( (2,2,(23,0,24,78,2)),
               (1,2,(1,79)           ),
               (2,3,(333,899,8)      ),
               (1,4,(3333,3353))
               )

conds = defaultdict(list)

for d,L,tu in conditions:
    conds[d].extend(map(('{:0%s}' % L).format,tu))

pat = ''.join( '(?!\d{%s}(?:%s))' % (k-1,'|'.join(conds[k]))
               for k in conds )
pat += '\d{5}'
print '\npat:\n',pat,'\n'

rgx = re.compile(pat)

for x in ('01655','02655','79443','78443',
          '12145','12245','12345','12456','12567',
          '278455','70245','13338','13348',
          '18997','18905','60089','60189',
          '33330','33530','33730'):
    print x,rgx.match(x)
```

result

```
pat:
(?!\d{0}(?:01|79|3333|3353))(?!\d{1}(?:23|00|24|78|02|333|899|008))\d{5} 

01655 None
02655 <_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x011DB528>
79443 None
78443 <_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x011DB528>
12145 <_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x011DB528>
12245 <_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x011DB528>
12345 None
12456 None
12567 <_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x011DB528>
278455 None
70245 None
13338 None
13348 <_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x011DB528>
18997 None
18905 <_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x011DB528>
60089 None
60189 <_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x011DB528>
33330 None
33530 None
33730 <_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x011DB528>
```

Comment: What if i want 10 digit string where starting digit is 3..
3283495322
3293495322
.
.
also string starting with 3 and 5....but not 3575 and 3576 

3575839205 - don't match

Comment: I'll answer if you explain with more precision all the conditions and variations of conditions you want. For the moemnt I hardly understand what you mean in your comment. Do you want the same exclusion from digit 3 than from digit 2 ? I don't undrstand the stuff concerning 3 and 5. Please, clarify.

Comment: ok. the earlier one was just example what i need (you can say part of it what i want). Below is full requirement
i want to match 10 digit number starting from 3
so now i have regex as '3\d{9}' 
but along with this i need to match specific range which starts with 35. Here i want to exclude the range having number 3575 and 3576

3(9digit) and 35(exclude75&76)(6digit)

Comment: You want to exclude only 3575\d\d\d\d\d\d and 3576\d\d\d\d\d\d ?

Comment: So the regex pattern is as simple as ``'3(?!575|576)\d{9}'``

Comment: Brilliant...awesome...thnx

Comment: I've posted an edit to give you idea of what can be done with a more complex code using regex. In case you need complex conditions, pattern can be constructed to hold a variety of conditions